# Matching in pandas dataframe (fuzzywuzzy)

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataframe with one column containing company names (the dataframe has approximately 50 columns). For example

```
Name
byname_tt
standing_re
mystandying_tz
mouse_x
mousepad_db
```

I'm trying to create one more column with a list of similar names from the name checked. To compare the names I'm using fuzzywuzzy.

```
def check_name(name):
    check = df.apply(lambda row: ((fuzz.partial_ratio(row['Name'], name)) >= 50), axis=1)
    return [df.Name[i] for i, x in enumerate(check) if x]
```

My expected output, in case the match is above the threshold, should be something like

```
 Name           Checked
    byname_tt      []
    standing_re    ['mystandying_tz']
    mystandying_tz ['standing_re']
    mouse_x        ['mousepad_db']
    mousepad_db    ['mouse_x']
```

Currently, my output is wrong:

```
 Name           Checked
    byname_tt      ['byname_tt']
    standing_re    ['standing_re']
    mystandying_tz ['mystandying_tz']
    mouse_x        ['mouse_x']
    mousepad_db    ['mousepad_db']
```

For each name in Name I should check the similarity with the other names within Name column.
Any idea on what's going wrong?

Comment: What is the name that is checked here? Do you check all company names against all other company names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re going to match all pairs of strings anyways, you could start by generating all these pairs you want to compare, and remove when twice the same word appears:

```
>>> pairs = pd.merge(df['Name'], df['Name'].rename('Checked'), how='cross', suffixes=('', ''))
>>> pairs = pairs[pairs['Name'] != pairs['Checked']]
```

Then you can use your fuzz library for comparison, I’ll be using python’s difflib for this example − it’s not necessarily better but it’ll avoid installing yet another package as it does roughly the same.

```
>>> pairs['ratio'] = pairs.agg(lambda s: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, s['Name'], s['Checked']).ratio(), axis='columns')
>>> pairs
              Name         Checked     ratio
1        byname_tt     standing_re  0.200000
2        byname_tt  mystandying_tz  0.347826
3        byname_tt         mouse_x  0.375000
4        byname_tt     mousepad_db  0.100000
5      standing_re       byname_tt  0.100000
7      standing_re  mystandying_tz  0.720000
8      standing_re         mouse_x  0.222222
9      standing_re     mousepad_db  0.363636
10  mystandying_tz       byname_tt  0.260870
11  mystandying_tz     standing_re  0.720000
13  mystandying_tz         mouse_x  0.285714
14  mystandying_tz     mousepad_db  0.400000
15         mouse_x       byname_tt  0.375000
16         mouse_x     standing_re  0.222222
17         mouse_x  mystandying_tz  0.285714
19         mouse_x     mousepad_db  0.666667
20     mousepad_db       byname_tt  0.300000
21     mousepad_db     standing_re  0.181818
22     mousepad_db  mystandying_tz  0.400000
23     mousepad_db         mouse_x  0.666667
```

And finally we can simply filter on the ratio and generate lists with a simple groupby:

```
>>> similar = pairs[pairs['ratio'] > .5].groupby('Name')['Checked'].agg(list)
>>> similar
Name
mouse_x              [mousepad_db]
mousepad_db              [mouse_x]
mystandying_tz       [standing_re]
standing_re       [mystandying_tz]
Name: Checked, dtype: object
>>> df.merge(similar.reindex(pairs['Name'].unique(), fill_value=[]), on='Name', how='outer')
             Name           Checked
0       byname_tt                []
1     standing_re  [mystandying_tz]
2  mystandying_tz     [standing_re]
3         mouse_x     [mousepad_db]
4     mousepad_db         [mouse_x]
```

The `reindex` at the end is a little workaround to get a fillna of `[]` on lines without matches, since you can’t pass a list as an argument to `fillna()`.

Comment: Thanks Cimbali. I am getting this error: ValueError: fill_value must be a scalar. Do you know how I can fix it or what I should look at to fix it?

Comment: @LdM I’ve updated that, fillna doesn’t accept lists as arugment.